Azure Face API SDK get photo in android after verify
I'm implementing the liveness system but I need to get the photo taken at the time of verification, but I didn't find a way to do this, I even tried to get a "print" of the preview on Android but it is displayed on a surfaceview, every attempt I make I did always return a blank image.
Is there any way to get this image still on android while checking this?
In the examples they do it like this:
open class LivenessActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
...
    override fun onResume() {
            super.onResume()
            if (mFaceAnalyzer == null) {
                initializeConfig()
                val visionSourceOptions = VisionSourceOptions(this, this as LifecycleOwner)
                // preview on surfaceView
                visionSourceOptions.setPreview(mSurfaceView)
                mVisionSource = VisionSource.fromDefaultCamera(visionSourceOptions)
                displayCameraOnLayout()
                createFaceAnalyzer()
    
            }
            startAnalyzeOnce()
        }

    private fun displayCameraOnLayout() {
        val previewSize = mVisionSource?.cameraPreviewFormat
        val params = mCameraPreviewLayout.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        params.dimensionRatio = previewSize?.height.toString() + ":" + previewSize?.width
        params.width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT
        params.matchConstraintDefaultWidth = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_CONSTRAINT_PERCENT
        params.matchConstraintPercentWidth = 0.8f
        mCameraPreviewLayout.layoutParams = params
    }

    private fun createFaceAnalyzer() {
        FaceAnalyzerCreateOptions().use { createOptions ->
            createOptions.setFaceAnalyzerMode(FaceAnalyzerMode.TRACK_FACES_ACROSS_IMAGE_STREAM)

            mFaceAnalyzer = FaceAnalyzerBuilder()
                .serviceOptions(mServiceOptions)
                .source(mVisionSource)
                .createOptions(createOptions)
                .build().get()
        }

        mFaceAnalyzer?.apply {
            this.analyzed.addEventListener(analyzedListener)
            this.analyzing.addEventListener(analyzingListener)
            this.stopped.addEventListener(stoppedListener)
        }
    }
...
}

I tried several ways to "print" the surfaceview since I didn't have direct access to the camera object but none of them worked:
private fun usePixelCopy(view: SurfaceView, callback: (String) -> Unit) {
    val bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.width, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)

    PixelCopy.request(view, bmp, {
        callback(bitmapToBase64(bmp))
    }, Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()))
}

Source: Link

Are you trying to get around requesting direct camera access? If so, I believe this question goes against all StackOverflow community guidelines.

@akseli In fact the lib does not provide (as far as it goes) a way to get the image that was taken during the verification, I'm trying to get around this, but if there is another way to do it I would like to know
